# problem curl Resource id #2 ssl test cacert.pem and not work

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I needed SSL to get this page. I first tested the localhost and used the cacert.pem file. Then I added to php.ini and again got the error. Finally I installed SSL on the server and got the error again. What is the problem?

```php
<?php
$ch = curl_init("https://ebanking.sbank.ir/IB-New/login/loginPage.action?ibReq=WEB");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookieFile");
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\binaries\php\cacert.pem");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec($ch);
$err_status = curl_error($ch);
echo $err_status;
echo $ch;
?>
```

Comment: can you state clearly what is the error message you get?

Comment: Resource id #2  Related to ssl